# Saving data in localstorage

Tags: javascript

I'm try to save data to localstorage. Created "class" through constructor and try to put get and set methods to them. But when I click my button(when button was clicked data must be saving) nothing happens(In developer tools "Resource" tab). When I tried simple save data through JSON.stringify and else all was worked.

```
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('buttonCreate').onclick = function() {
      var topicValue = document.getElementById("create-topic").value;
      var statusValue = document.getElementById("create-status").value;
      var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("create-description").value;
      var storage = new Storage();
      var ticket = {
        topic: topicValue,
        status: statusValue,
        description: descriptionValue
      };
      storage.set("Item", item);
    }
  }
})();
```

"class" Storage:

```
function Storage() {
  this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR = 'items';
}
Storage.prototype.get = function() {
  var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem(this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR);
  return fromStorage ? JSON.parse(fromStorage) : [];
};
Storage.prototype.set = function(key, items) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(items));
};
```

Comment: Your getter is referencing `this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR`, but your setter is not.

Comment: `storage.set("Item", item)`... but there's no `item` variable defined.

Comment: ^ After fixing that, [your code works fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/mysjxekr/)

Answer (score 0):

The exact issue with your code is the storage key and also the `item` that you are trying to store which is not defined.

- It stores it in to `Item` key and the get method is written to take it from the key, `items`.
- by looking at the given code, you should suppose to store `ticket` object. `storage.set(ticket);`

**A suggested better approach**: To pass a `key` to instantiate `Storage` object and then use it accordingly.

Such as `var storage = new Storage('Item');`

```
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('buttonCreate').onclick = function() {
      var topicValue = document.getElementById("create-topic").value;
      var statusValue = document.getElementById("create-status").value;
      var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("create-description").value;
      var storage = new Storage("ticket");
      var ticket = {
        topic: topicValue,
        status: statusValue,
        description: descriptionValue
      };
      storage.set(ticket);
    }
  }
})();
```

"class" Storage:

```
function Storage(key) {
  this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR = key;
}
Storage.prototype.get = function() {
  var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem(this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR);
  return fromStorage ? JSON.parse(fromStorage) : {};
};
Storage.prototype.set = function(item) {
  localStorage.setItem(this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR, JSON.stringify(item));
};
```

To get the ticket value stored in localstorage:

```
var storage = new Storage('ticket');
var ticket = storage.get();
```

Comment: While this could be a better design depending on OPs needs, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: The exact issue with the original code is the storage key. It stores it in to `Item` and the get method is written to take it from `items`. :)

Comment: No it isn't. They aren't even using `get`. The problem is they're referencing a variable (`item`) which doesn't exist. You are right that currently `get` *will* be broken when they use it but that's a different problem. Currently, they aren't able to even save anything with the `set` function, regardless of key.

Answer (score -1):

Per Mike McCaughan's comment, you were referencing an undefined variable.

Using strict mode would have caught this.

You have another bug in the keys used to address items in storage:

```
'items' !== 'Item'
```

Also; you have no classes in your code.

Comment: I think by "class" they mean they have a constructor. Also, it doesn't matter what the key is; they're saying it wasn't saving at all. Although that would become an issue later when trying to use `get`.